# I implement this sound but it is in my other layers as well

Tags: iphone, ios5, audio, cocos2d-iphone

The switch button appears in all my other layers and I was wondering if there is a way to only appear in a certain layer.

.h file

```
 UISwitch *muteSwitch;
```

.m file

```
     muteSwitch = [[ UISwitch alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 290, 0, 0) ];
       muteSwitch.on = YES;
    [muteSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(soundOnOrOff:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:muteSwitch];
    [muteSwitch release];            





  - (void)soundOnOrOff:(id)sender
  {

     if ([[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] mute]) {
    // This will unmute the sound
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setMute:0];
    }
else {
    //This will mute the sound
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setMute:1];
}

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite normal because you add your slider on the top of the GLView. So even if you change the scene the slider will stay here.
If you want remove it, you just have to call the `[muteSwitch removeFromSuperview]` when you change your scene.

I should you to use the CCControlSwitch from the [CCControlExtension](https://github.com/YannickL/CCControlExtension) because it is build with Cocos2D and it works as any other Cocos2D component. Moreover you can custom it as you want.